# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'brownie._cli'

Tags: python, ganache-cli, brownie

After installing python3, ganache-cli, upgrading pip to pipx and installing eth-brownie.. I am receiving errors when trying to use "brownie".

I followed all of the steps in their docs correctly and have tried the alternative ways to install it, but I can't seem to figure out why brownie is not being recognized as a module. It said it was installed globally, by the way.

These are the errors I get when trying to use the *brownie* command.

[image]

Does anyone understand what is going on? If I try using the command *py -m brownie*, it returns the error *'brownie' is a package and cannot be directly executed*

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had installed eth-brownie with both pip and pipx. This must have caused some complications when locating and trying to run the scrips. Uninstalling it from both and then reinstalling it with only pipx did the trick.

Comment: getting similar issue with macos and python3.9. tried re-install but not working. any alternatives?

Comment: I'd say try uninstalling every version of whatever software/package you are having issues with. Once you have it all uninstalled, then reinstall your desired version. This will help reset certain scripts or environment variables that may be pointing to the wrong software/version folders. Don't have too much details about your issue but I hope that helps.

Comment: I have tried to install it in virtual environment instead of installing it globally. its working fine.