# What is the recommended way to setup brownie project?

Tags: brownie

So as to run the brownie cli I have to install browine as

```
python3 -m pip install --user pipx
python3 -m pipx ensurepath
pipx install eth-brownie
```

But to import and playaround the brownie modules it seems I have to again pip install as:

```
python -m venv myvenv
source ./myenv/bin activate
pip install eth-brownine
```

By doing so I found it not following **DRY***(as eth-brownie is installedtwice). Is there any better approach to configure brownie??

Answer (score 1):

It works fine to just do `pip install eth-brownie`, at least for me on OS X Big Sur.

Installing with both techniques would definitely be a bad idea. For example this person had problems caused by installing with both pipx and pip: [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'brownie._cli'](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/100035/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-brownie-cli)